# React Native app cannot be installed properly

Tags: react-native

I am creating a new app in React Native, but every time when I install my app in CMD I get this error:

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact react-native-scripts` failed
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your error ?

Comment: now check the scren shot

Answer (score 0):

just do

npm install

and everything in your package.json will be installed and added to your node_modules

Comment: try npm install -g react-native-cli

then you can create a project using
react-native init project_name

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of Node js.

Then run

```
npm cache clean or yarn cache clean
install create-react-native-app globally
run create-react-native-app some-project-name
```

Comment: @bilalahmad123456 did u try this?